# excel VBA trying to change properties of buttons, get runtime error 434

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a neat (or hopefully at least useful) excel template for others to use. Wont bother you with more specifics about it...

However, I'm trying to lock some buttons to cover whole cells which will change color when clicked. But when I open it on another computer the exact size is a tiny bit different so in Workbook_Open I'm trying to set the widths of the buttons and for some reason only a few of them lets me do this..

All of the buttons are activeX-buttons and according to me should work exactly the same.

```html
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   
    ' Yellow/green buttons
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton1.Width = Range(Cells(16, 6), Cells(16, 6)).Width
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton2.Width = Range(Cells(21, 6), Cells(21, 6)).Width
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton3.Width = Range(Cells(32, 6), Cells(32, 6)).Width
    '''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton4.Widht = Range(Cells(33, 6), Cells(33, 6)).Width / 3
    '''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton5.Widht = Range(Cells(33, 6), Cells(33, 6)).Width / 3
    '''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton6.Widht = Range(Cells(33, 6), Cells(33, 6)).Width / 3
    '''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton7.Widht = Range(Cells(35, 6), Cells(35, 6)).Width
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton8.Width = Range(Cells(47, 6), Cells(47, 6)).Width
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton9.Width = Range(Cells(48, 6), Cells(48, 6)).Width
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton10.Width = Range(Cells(49, 6), Cells(49, 6)).Width / 2
    '''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton11.witdh = Range(Cells(49, 6), Cells(49, 6)).Width / 2

End sub
```

The lines with ''' are the buttons that return
"error 434 object does not support this method or property"

Comment: you've spelled width worng

Comment: Yeah, just found out.. Was starring myself blind on the screen thinking wtf is going on but yeah, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spelling is important ;)

```
'''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton4.Widht = Range(Cells(33, 6), Cells(33, 6)).Width / 3
'''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton5.Widht = Range(Cells(33, 6), Cells(33, 6)).Width / 3
'''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton6.Widht = Range(Cells(33, 6), Cells(33, 6)).Width / 3
'''ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CommandButton7.Widht = Range(Cells(35, 6), Cells(35, 6)).Width
```

Try to exchange **Widht** with **Width**

By the way the *Object doesnt support this property or method* is a big giveaway. Anytime you get this error check the called methods and the name of your variables. It's likely that you misspelled one on them.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem.

Many thanks!